# select form not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

Please help! My code is not working and I cannot figure out why.

```
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        echo '<li>'.($i + 1).'.) '.product_select('id_produkt'.$i+1).' name=   id_produkt'.($i+1).'</li>';
    } 
?>
```

This code is in my form HTML. product_select() function:

```
function product_select($name) {
    global $db_connection;

    $query = "SELECT `id_produkt`, `nazov`, `kod_produktu` FROM `produkty` ORDER BY `id_produkt`";
    $result = mysql_query($query, $db_connection) or die(mysql_error());

    $select = '<select name="'.$name.'">';
    $select .= '<option value="0" selected>Vyberte produkt</option>';

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $select .= '<option value="'.$row['id_produkt'].'">('.$row['kod_produktu'].') '.$row['nazov'].'</option>';
    }

    $select .= '</select>';

    return $select;
}
```

function is in a file, which is "require_once", $_POST['id_produkt1'] is still empty

Comment: where is your html form in php showing the post

Comment: "My code is not working and I cannot figure out why." what are you intending to do, it isnt clear...

Comment: What error you seeing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked the code in my IDE. The error is when you pass the argument in the `product_select` function.
Just replace 
`product_select('id_produkt'.$i+1)` with 
`product_select('id_produkt'.($i+1))` (notice the brackets) and You're code will be fine. 
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

That is going to produce invalid HTML. Remove the

> ' name=   id_produkt'.($i+1).'

from your top section, and it will be valid.